# TailwindCSS isn't working as expected on Android WebView

Tags: java, android, css, tailwind-css

I have created a simply WebView-App on Android Studio:

```
WebView = findViewById(R.id.WebView);
WebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
getSupportActionBar().hide();
WebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

The app works as expected (tailwind.css and index.html are loaded fine) but some features of tailwind.css doesn't work, I added a simple button:

```
<div class="float-right">
     <button class="h-16 px-10 m-2 text-lg text-indigo-100 transition-colors duration-150 bg-indigo-700 rounded-lg focus:shadow-outline hover:bg-indigo-800">LOGIN</button>
</div>
```

But the button has no (background)-color (using desktop version of chrome it will be rendered as expected with a background-color) but float-right for example works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some tailwind classes only work beyond a certain version of webiew. With webview version 74, tailwind color classes work, but spacing classes like `gap` don't. In webview version 103 all classes seem to work normally. Updating webdriver version should solve this problem.